# Posts feed number of posts

Tags: posts, wp-query, actions, child-theme

Happy Holidays everyone! I hope you can help me with this 'little' problem I'm having :)

I am using a child theme based on [Elara](https://www.lyrathemes.com/elara/) which displays the posts feed in different formats on the front page and on the archive pages. The main difference is that on the front page the design best suits 8 posts while on the archive pages it best fits 10 posts before navigation.

However, there is no option to specify the different limits. As far as I can tell the feed is controlled by this:

```
<?php
/**
 * The loop / blog feed
 *
 * @package elara
 */
?>

<div id="blog-feed" class="section-feed row">
    <?php
        /**
         * The loop
         *
         * For covering all customizer options from above, take a look at elara's feed.php
         */
        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

        endwhile; endif;
    ?>
</div><!-- section-feed row -->
```

Then the content part of the code is this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Main template for displaying a post within a feed
 *
 * @package elara
 */
$elara_class = elara_set_feed_post_class(); ?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'entry matcheight ' . esc_attr( $elara_class ) ); ?>>

    <?php elara_entry_thumbnail( 'elara-archive', true ); ?>

    <footer class="entry-meta">
        <div>
            <?php elara_entry_categories(); ?>
            <?php elara_entry_separator( 'categories-date' ); ?>
            <?php elara_entry_date(); ?>
        </div>
        <div>
            <?php elara_entry_author(); ?>
            <?php elara_entry_separator( 'author-comments' ); ?>
            <?php elara_entry_comments_link(); ?>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <?php elara_entry_title(); ?>
    <?php elara_feed_entry_excerpt(); ?>

    <?php
        /**
         * Get video modal for video post format
         */
        get_template_part( 'parts/entry', 'video-modal' );
    ?>

</article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```

So, my question is: can you help me customize it so the frontpage displays 8 posts before prev/next page navigation controls while the archive pages display 10 posts?

Comment: Create your own loop for either front or archive using [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters) utilizing [`posts_per_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters) parameter.

Comment: @MaxYudin, I thought that I would have to create my own loop, however my knowledge is quite limited and am unsure how to make it specific to the archive pages and not the frontpage. Also, would I do this on the same .php file (the feed.php)?

Comment: You don't have to create loop - just use pre_get_posts filter action...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so this theme uses global `$wp_query` to print these posts. It makes it pretty easy to change the number of posts... All you have to do is to use `pre_get_posts` action and change query params.

```
function my_change_number_of_posts( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ( is_home() ) {  // change only for home page
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 8 );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_change_number_of_posts' );
```

Of course you can modify the conditions in that action, to achieve exactly what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved it quite elegantly!

Comment: I'm glad it solved your problem :)